# PHPMailer error - HTML email error

Tags: html, parsing, phpmailer

I am new to PHP and recently I installed  PHPMailer using Composer in my system. I am facing problem with an HTML message that I am trying to send.

I have tried to send plain text and it is working fine and getting the response of the PHPmailer.

Below is my code :

```
    <?php 
    require_once 'autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'email@exapmle.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->From="mailer@example.com";
    $mail->FromName="My site's mailer";
    $mail->Sender="mailer@example.com";
    $mail->AddReplyTo("replies@example.com", "Replies for my site");

    $mail->AddAddress("receiver@example.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Test 1";

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Body = '<html>
    <head>
    <link href="http://alikan.esy.es/Untitled1.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://alikan.esy.es/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://alikan.esy.es/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://alikan.esy.es/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://alikan.esy.es/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.css">
    <script src="http://alikan.esy.es/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="http://alikan.esy.es/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="http://alikan.esy.es/wwb10.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:223px;top:70px;width:250px;height:16px;z-index:0;text-align:left;">
    <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;"><a href="javascript:displaylightbox('http://www.google.com/index.php',{width:1000,height:1000})" target="_self">This is an email body</a></span></div></body></html>';
    $mail->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
       echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "Letter is sent";
    }
    ?>
```

And this is the error code that i get after trying to send it :

```
    ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\vendor\index.php on line 37
```

Answer (score 0):

You opened the body string with a single quote `'`:

```
$mail->Body = '<html>...
```

And you use it again in your html string to declare a parameter:

```
...javascript:displaylightbox('http://www.google.com/index.php',...
```

If your string is delimited by single or double quotes, if it contains the **same character** it must be escaped, otherwise the php parser will think that your string ends at the next occurrence of the opening quote. If you delimit with single quotes using double ones in the content without escaping is ok, and vice versa.

Fix it escaping those two `'` this way:

```
...javascript:displaylightbox(\'http://www.google.com/index.php\',...
```

Edit:

Furthermore, if you are sending an html body, remember to set the `isHTML` flag before sending the mail:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I really do appreciate it, I´ve tried your suggestion and the emai gets sent but the message received is only a non-clickable text (plain text) ...

Comment: You need to add `$mail->IsHTML(true);`.

Comment: Thank you once more but if you check the code source well you will notice that i already included $mail->IsHTML(true); and to let you know i´ve tried it both ways before the $mail->Body and after it  and it didn't work ...

Comment: Ok, i've seen it and the code should be correct now. The html is displayed as text (tags displayed in clear as text) or just when you click the link nothing happens?

Comment: When i click the link nothing happens... Thank you once more

Comment: If you have tried that code in a browser and it works it could be that the mail program you are using is not loading external js, try adding an image and verify it works...

Comment: Thans for your answer, I just tried sending an external image and it worked ... so what do you sugges ?

Comment: Try with another email client and see if something change, i don't see other issues here...